# Importing points from CSV file with NaN as vertical separator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, import, polyline-creation, xy

I am importing a CSV file with the coordinates of several points forming some kind of circle structure. The different circles are separated in the file table with one line of NaN, NaN.

When I import it and use the **Points to path** tool the circles get connected with each other.

[image]

How can I prevent this connecting line? Is there a way to separate the line afterwards or should I import the file differently?

This is the content of the CSV file (x,y); UTM 25 North

```
564074.539810113,4127429.031241
564084.084644733,4127423.97809326
564090.822175054,4127417.8020238
564100.367009675,4127412.1874152
564108.788922575,4127407.69572832
564116.649374616,4127402.08111972
564126.755670097,4127395.3435894
564136.300504718,4127388.60605908
564141.353652458,4127383.55291134
564147.529721919,4127380.18414618
564157.636017399,4127375.13099844
564168.30377374,4127370.0778507
564174.479843201,4127367.83200726
564183.463216961,4127365.58616382
564199.184121043,4127360.53301608
564221.642555444,4127352.67256404
564237.924920386,4127347.05795544
564256.453128767,4127342.0048077
564283.964710909,4127333.02143394
564307.487842143,4127327.27413744
564307.978717545,4127310.58437375
564306.99696674,4127291.44023305
564298.161209495,4127268.85996453
564289.816327652,4127252.66107625
564288.343701444,4127242.3526928
564285.889324432,4127224.68117831
564270.181311551,4127208.97316543
564263.309055915,4127194.24690335
564257.418551085,4127182.46589369
564257.418551085,4127169.21225782
564259.872928098,4127140.74148447
564265.272557525,4127121.10646837
564270.181311551,4127105.39845549
564272.285684698,4127089.36384791
564271.303933893,4127073.65583503
564266.395179867,4127061.87482537
564261.486425842,4127052.54819272
564254.614170207,4127040.76718306
564247.251039169,4127029.9679242
564239.887908131,4127015.24166213
564223.198144445,4126993.64314441
564217.307639615,4126987.75263958
564187.36424006,4126959.28186624
564176.074105802,4126963.20886946
564165.274846947,4126969.59024969
564148.585083261,4126974.49900372
564132.87707038,4126976.46250533
564125.513939342,4126976.95338073
564121.586936122,4126987.75263958
564106.860674046,4126995.11577062
564088.698284152,4126997.57014763
564078.389900699,4127001.49715086
564072.545572287,4127010.83505127
564060.764562626,4127015.25292989
564054.383182394,4127015.25292989
564048.001802161,4127018.19818231
564038.675169513,4127023.59781174
564030.821163072,4127030.47006737
564026.403284449,4127033.41531979
564021.003655022,4127033.90619519
564009.222645361,4127041.76020163
563998.914261908,4127041.76020163
563989.58762926,4127053.54121129
563981.242747417,4127054.03208669
563968.479986951,4127062.37696854
563956.208101888,4127067.28572256
563951.299347863,4127068.26747337
563951.299347863,4127073.17622739
563943.936216825,4127073.17622739
563931.664331762,4127077.10323061
563938.045711994,4127095.26562051
563938.536587397,4127113.4280104
563944.91796763,4127129.62689868
563951.299347863,4127136.49915432
563961.116855913,4127153.188918
563970.443488561,4127184.11406836
563974.370491782,4127196.87682883
563973.388740976,4127221.42059896
563978.21506898,4127226.38889131
563982.1420722,4127231.78852074
563987.050826225,4127235.22464856
563990.977829446,4127240.13340258
563996.868334276,4127248.96915983
563999.813586691,4127255.84141546
564006.685842326,4127257.80491707
564012.576347157,4127268.60417593
564019.448602792,4127273.02205455
564025.829983025,4127282.8395626
564031.720487855,4127286.76656582
564039.083618893,4127291.67531985
564042.028871308,4127299.03845088
564048.410251541,4127304.43808031
564051.355503956,4127313.27383756
564050.373753151,4127327.50922423
564050.373753151,4127340.2719847
564050.373753151,4127352.54386976
564050.373753151,4127365.79750563
564053.319005567,4127374.14238747
564056.755133384,4127381.50551851
564056.755133384,4127389.85040035
564055.773382579,4127399.6679084
564057.246008787,4127408.99454105
564063.62738902,4127416.84854749
564065.59089063,4127419.79379991
564069.095067605,4127423.10252273
564070.962675979,4127426.9622467
564071.709719329,4127429.20337675
564073.950849377,4127429.20337675
NaN,NaN
563511.927772633,4127271.82685267
563512.560456485,4127281.9497943
563515.723875746,4127288.90931668
563523.316081972,4127303.46104527
563530.275604345,4127320.54350928
563534.071707458,4127333.82987018
563546.725384501,4127337.62597329
563553.052223023,4127352.81038574
563561.909796953,4127364.19869508
563570.134687031,4127376.21968827
563576.461525552,4127381.91384294
563583.421047926,4127393.93483613
563594.809357264,4127400.26167465
563601.136195786,4127411.64998399
563611.891821272,4127421.14024177
563618.851343646,4127429.36513185
563623.280130611,4127436.32465423
563629.606969132,4127448.34564742
563634.66843995,4127457.20322135
563643.52601388,4127466.69347913
563659.343110183,4127470.48958224
563672.629471078,4127473.6530015
563688.446567382,4127473.6530015
563702.365612129,4127475.55105306
563723.876863102,4127474.28568535
563737.163223997,4127474.28568535
563747.286165632,4127462.26469216
563753.613004153,4127452.14175053
563761.837894231,4127427.4670803
563761.837894231,4127413.54803555
563766.899365048,4127400.89435851
563777.022306683,4127389.50604917
563792.206719134,4127383.8118945
563808.023815438,4127379.38310753
563825.106279446,4127372.42358516
563836.494588784,4127367.99479819
563868.761465244,4127359.13722426
563875.720987618,4127342.68744411
563887.741980808,4127338.891341
563879.51709073,4127322.44156084
563870.6595168,4127294.60347135
563862.434626722,4127278.15369119
563850.413633532,4127256.00975636
563853.577052792,4127231.33508613
563847.250214271,4127216.15067368
563837.759956489,4127204.12968049
563827.637014854,4127195.27210656
563819.412124777,4127184.51648107
563811.187234699,4127176.29159099
563798.533557656,4127166.16864936
563787.145248317,4127159.84181084
563780.185725943,4127156.04570772
563766.266681196,4127154.14765617
563758.041791118,4127159.84181084
563750.449584892,4127164.90328166
563746.65348178,4127164.90328166
563742.224694815,4127173.76085558
563730.203701624,4127178.8223264
563715.019289172,4127181.35306181
563708.692450651,4127188.94526804
563692.875354347,4127190.84331959
563679.588993452,4127203.49699664
563664.404581,4127195.90479041
563648.587484697,4127204.76236434
563633.403072245,4127214.88530597
563625.178182167,4127221.2121445
563611.891821272,4127220.57946064
563589.747886447,4127231.96776998
563573.298106291,4127240.82534391
563558.746377692,4127247.78486629
563543.56196524,4127253.47902096
563530.275604345,4127260.43854333
563522.68339812,4127263.60196259
563514.458508042,4127268.66343341
563513.825824189,4127270.56148496
```

Comment: Do the points have an attribute field to indicate which "circle" they belong to?

Comment: Can you post your csv or at least a sample of it, showing the structure, expecially the `NaN` part?

Comment: I added a sample of the file. Unfortunately I just have x and y coordinates. It is supposed to represent one of three different substrates of an area.

Comment: Better add the CSV as text, not as image as like this, we can't use it for testing

Comment: How are your Python skills?  You could read and rewrite the CSV file such that each row between each nan sections get some  circle ID value, and you can purge the nan rows.  That code would depend on what the first two rows look like.  Can you post the CSV file like Babel asks?

Comment: Posted, i hope its fine like this :) Uff, Python skills are not really there, but i could get into that if thats a way to go. I was thinking maybe I am doing something wrong by importing the data and I could somehow set the NaN as a seperator

Comment: What is the coordinate system

Comment: Is it just this one file with two lines or are there others and more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This script will return a new text file where each group of coordinates bound by a NaN, NaN will share a unique `"ID"`. The NaN, NaN rows are removed.

You will have to alter the path to your `incsv` file and the `outcsv` file. Then, just paste the code into the QGIS Python window.

```py
incsv = r"C:\csvparse.txt"
outcsv = r"C:\csvfixed.txt"
counter = 1

incsv = open(incsv,'r')
outcsv = open(outcsv, 'w')

lines = incsv.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print(line)
    if line.find('NaN,NaN') != -1:
        counter += 1
    else:
        outline = str(counter)+','+line
        outcsv.writelines(outline)
incsv.close()
outcsv.close()
```

Open the resulting output file and add a new row at the top like ID, x, y as appropriate for your data.

[image]

Finally, use the [Points to Path](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#points-to-path) tool to build your final polygon data.
[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked even better and I just did it for all my files :) Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 6):

You can:

1. Add the coordinates as a delimited text layer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. [DBSSCAN clustering](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgisdbscanclustering) with `Minimum cluster size = 2` and `Maximum distance between points = 50`. This will add the attribute CLUSTER_ID to the points, one id for each cluster/ring of points.
3. Point to path with `CLUSTER_ID` as group expression:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked and was super helpful! I can only estimate the maximum distance between the circles, right? Because I have more files with many more and closer circles, but I can just try several values and check the result.

Comment: Nice! Yes you will have to adjust it so it the clusters are correct. As small as possible but large enough for all points in each circle to be assign the same cluster

Answer (score 3):

Building on [@GBG's great answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/462040/2856), you could use a [processing script](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html) that converts the CSV to a format that Points to path can use.

[image]

```py
from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingException
from pathlib import Path
import csv


@alg(name="fixcsv", label=alg.tr("Fix CSV"), group='examplescripts', group_label='Example scripts')
@alg.input(type=alg.FILE, name="INPUT_CSV", label="Input CSV")
@alg.input(type=alg.FILE, name="OUTPUT_CSV", label="Output CSV")
@alg.output(type=alg.FILE, name="OUTPUT", label="Output CSV")
def fix_csv(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """Fix NaN, NaN CSV"""

    try:
        input = instance.parameterAsString(parameters, "INPUT_CSV", context)
        output = instance.parameterAsString(parameters, "OUTPUT_CSV", context)

        counter = 1
        with open(input,'r') as incsv, open(output, 'w') as outcsv:
            csvreader = csv.reader(incsv)
            csvwriter = csv.writer(outcsv)
            csvwriter.writerow(["ID", "X", "Y"])
            for row in csvreader:
                if row == []:
                    continue
                elif row == ["NaN","NaN"]:
                    counter += 1
                else:
                    outrow = [counter] + row
                    csvwriter.writerow(outrow)
        
        return {'OUTPUT': output}

    except Exception as err:
        raise QgsProcessingException(f"Unable to fix {parameters['INPUT_CSV']}:\n{err}")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

##### Version 1:

Use this expression with Geometry generator on the CSV layer:

```
case 
when @id = 1 
then 
with_variable(
    'last',
    array_find (array_agg (attribute (@feature,'field_1') ='nan'), 1),
        collect_geometries(
            with_variable (
            'mp',
            map (minimum(@id),@last,@last+2,maximum (@id)),
            array_foreach (
                map_akeys (@mp),
                make_polygon (
                    close_line (
                        make_line (
                            array_foreach (
                                generate_series (@element, map_get (@mp, @element)),
                                geometry (get_feature_by_id (@layer,@element))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
end
```

##### Version 2:

1. Load your csv, export the layer as Geopackage
2. Apply the expression beneath the screenshot with Geoemtry generator to create the polygons:

[image]

```
case 
when @id = minimum (@id)
then  collect_geometries (
        array_foreach(
            array (1, (array_find (array_agg("field_1" ),0)+2)-1),
                make_polygon(
                    close_line( 
                        make_line (
                            array_foreach (
                                generate_series (
                                    @element, 
                                    case when @element = 1 
                                    then (array_find (array_agg("field_1" ),0)) 
                                    else array_length(array_agg("field_1")) 
                                    end
                                ),
                                geometry (get_feature_by_id (@layer, @element))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
end
```